# Define a new ex command active only in specific filetype (C++)

Tags: regular-expression, command-line, buffers, autocmd, replace

I would like to define a new command for C++ files/buffers (`ft=cpp`).

I shall explain the requirements through the example below. The newly defined command `:stripdbg` should strip the surrounding `dbg()` text and should accept an address range. e.g `:10,20stripdbg`, `:.,$stripdbg`, `:%stripdbg` etc should be possible and work as expected.

#### example.cpp

```cpp
#include "dbg.h"
#include <vector>


int factorial(int n) {
  if (dbg(n <= 1)) {
    return dbg(1);
  } else {
    return dbg(n * factorial(n - 1));
  }
}

int main() {
  std::string message = "hello";
  dbg(message); // [example.cpp:15 (main)] message = "hello" (std::string)

  const int a = 2;
  const int b = dbg(3 * a) + 1; // [example.cpp:18 (main)] 3 * a = 6 (int)

  std::vector<int> numbers{b, 13, 42};
  dbg(numbers); // [example.cpp:21 (main)] numbers = {7, 13, 42} (size: 3)
                // (std::vector<int>)

  dbg("this line is executed"); // [example.cpp:23 (main)] this line is executed

  factorial(4);

  return 0;
}
```

How can we achieve this through `.vimrc` settings?

### Update: Desired output after `%StripDbg()`

#### Background

The [`dbg.h` project](https://github.com/sharkdp/dbg-macro) is extremely helpful for quick debugging without the need for setting up/configuring and stepping through a command-line `gdb` process for a C++ codebase. For instance, this proves to be extremely helpful for one-off debugging in the 'coding test' round of an interview for a software development position. Quite a few tech companies use [Codility](https://www.codility.com/) for **timed** coding tasks. For such a use, offline development and quick debugging using `dbg` works perfectly. When the code works as expected, then we just need to strip out the `dbg()` calls and copy it into the browser, so that the online compiler in codility does not error out during grading.

So, my expected output after running `:%StripDbg` shall be,

#### example_strippeddbg.cpp (just an illustrative filename for distinction. The proposed command does not affect the filename)

```cpp
#include "dbg.h"
#include <vector>


int factorial(int n) {
  if (n <= 1) {           //  __stripped debug__
    return 1;             //  __stripped debug__
  } else {
    return n * factorial(n - 1);   //  __stripped debug__
  }
}

int main() {
  std::string message = "hello";
  message;  //  __stripped debug__

  const int a = 2;
  const int b = 3 * a + 1; //  __stripped debug__

  std::vector<int> numbers{b, 13, 42};
  numbers; //  __stripped debug__

  dbg("this line is executed");  // __Ideally, this line must be deleted__ This might be hard.

  factorial(4);

  return 0;
}
```

The only hard to tackle case might be `dbg("this line is executed");` which should ideally be **deleted** , but if that is not possible, should be left untouched. I don't wish to consider nested `dbg()` cases.

In summary, I am looking for the opposite of `surround.vim` for the specific `dbg()` regex sequence, but available as a standard `ex` command.

Comment: Depending on what you want the end result to be, the command itself could be a simple `:g/dbg(/d`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I doubt it. With that command `if (dbg(` would be deleted and I assume this is not what OP wants.

Comment: @MaximKim fair enough—but a substitute *could* reasonably do it , and those take ranges too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Maxin's answer, I'd recommend to use a ftplugin. They're really made to store the definition of filetype related mappings, commands, abbreviations, options, variables...

While we shall use `<buffer>`  with mappings and abbreviations, it's `-b`  with commands.

Now the problem is that you want to implement is quite complex. Vim main tool is regex. And regex don't support recursive patterns. Unfortunately, in your case, we need them to handle a variety of situations like `dbg(f(x, g(y, z))) + dbg(u+v)`: we have parenthesis within calls to `dbg`, and several uses of `dbg` on a same line.

I'd say at best we could start from tricks like this one: https://old.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/5nf4pb/some_help_needed_about_a_vim_regex_for_a_plugin/dcbhavc/

If we simplify it (a little), it becomes.

```
   " ~/.vimrc
   filetype plugin on " at least!


    " ~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp/StripDebug.vim
    command! -bang -buffer -range StripDbg <line1>,<line2>call s:StripDbg("<bang>")
    
    let s:SINGLEQUOTED = '''\%(\\.\|[^\\'']\+\)*'''
    let s:DOUBLEQUOTED = '"\%(\\.\|[^\\"]\+\)*"'
    let s:NEUTRAL      = '[^''"\[\](){}]\+'
    let s:TERMINAL     = s:NEUTRAL . '\|' . s:SINGLEQUOTED . '\|' . s:DOUBLEQUOTED
    let s:BALANCED     = '\%(' . s:TERMINAL . '\)*'
    
    for n in range(5)
      let s:PARENTHESIZED   = '(' . s:BALANCED . ')'
      let s:BALANCED        = '\%(' . s:TERMINAL . '\|' . s:PARENTHESIZED . '\)*'
    endfor
    
    function! s:StripDbg(bang) range abort
      let confirm = a:bang == '!' ? '' : 'c'
      exe a:firstline.','.a:lastline.'s/\<dbg(\('.s:BALANCED.'\))/\1/g'.confirm
    endfunction
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't handle cases where you use `gdb` to log variables.  I guess you'd need to write a refactoring plugin for clang-tidy & co in order to detect that the expression returned by `gdb` is used elsewhere.

I'm not sure whether the solution should not be to use macro at code level. Something like

```cpp
template <typename T>
inline
decltype(auto) dbg(T && v) { // not sure about the best parameters and return type to use
#if ! defined(DEBUG)
    spdlog::debug("DGB: {}", v);
#endif
    return std::forward<T>(v);
}
```

Comment: There are also cases when dbg is commented, in a string or it might be multilined. So clarification is still needed on what exactly OP wants. Also if you strip `dbg("bla bla")` then it would make cpp compiler unhappy.

Comment: @MaximKim, you're right. I wanted to add a note about the multi-lines case as well but forgot about it. My solution doesn't handle this case. Regarding `"bla bla";`, C++ compiler will ignore it. At best we have a warning: `warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]`

Comment: @LucHermitte Well, I am thankful for your in-depth answer, and the technical depth of your explanation and the effort you took in helping me out. My case is far too simple (atleast initially). I just need to strip out `dbg` so that the code become portable and works on any development environment that only has the standard library (after commenting out `dbg.h`).  I have now updated the question to clarify what exactly I am looking for. Would you be happy to refine/revise your answer to fine-tune to my requirements?

Comment: @Krishna, have you tried my solution? It exactly does what you're looking for (and a little bit more as it also supports side cases like `dbg(f(x, g(y, z)))` or `dbg(x) + dbg(u+v)` -- we need recursive regex for the first, and `:s`  and not `:g`  for the second . The only thing it cannot do: remove unused values and expressions. You'll have to use your linter or your compiler warning for this last part.

Comment: @LucHermitte I have tried your solution. I get an error `E118: Too many arguments for function: <SNR>112_StripDbg`, any thoughts?  Also, this seems to not work with `neovim`?

Comment: Sorry. When I edited my message, I forgot to add the bang parameter to the function. I fix that.

Comment: @Luc Hermitte thank you. That worked!

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot have a command started with lowercase letter, use `:Stripdbg` or `:StripDbg`
2. To define a command available only in specific filetype you can define it in autocommand event with `-buffer` parameter:

```
augroup cpp_group | au!
    au FileType cpp command! -buffer StripDbg call StripDbg()
augroup end
```

3. You have to implement `StripDbg()` function to do actual stripping
4. To add a range to your command add `-range` parameter and prepend `<line1>,<line2>` range to a function call:

```
augroup cpp_group | au!
    au FileType cpp command! -buffer -range StripDbg <line1>,<line2>call StripDbg()
augroup end
```

5. You can use implicit `a:firstline`, `a:lastline` variables to go through the range and use help of [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin (you have to install it).

```
func! StripDbg() range
    for lnr in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
        if getline(lnr) =~ 'dbg\s*('
            call search('dbg\s*(', "W", line(lnr))
            " delete dbg leaving cursor on a (
            " here we use normal with ! to call default mappings
            normal! dw
            " use vim-surround mapping to remove ( )
            " note, here we use normal without !, to call mapping of vim-surround
            normal dsb
        endif
    endfor 
endfunc
```

The result of `:%StripDbg` is:

```
#include "dbg.h"
#include <vector>


int factorial(int n) {
  if (n <= 1) {           //  __stripped debug__
    return 1;             //  __stripped debug__
  } else {
    return n * factorial(n - 1);   //  __stripped debug__
  }
}

int main() {
  std::string message = "hello";
  message;  //  __stripped debug__

  const int a = 2;
  const int b = 3 * a + 1; //  __stripped debug__

  std::vector<int> numbers{b, 13, 42};
  numbers; //  __stripped debug__

  "this line is executed";  // __Ideally, this line must be deleted__ This might be hard.

  factorial(4);

  return 0;
}
```

NOTE, it doesn't take into account `dbg("this line is executed")` should be removed. But you can add this kind of checks to the function yourself.
Also, if there are more then 1 `dbg` calls on the same line, only first one would be stripped.

**UPDATE**

Simpler solution using help of the `:global` command:

```
func! StripDbg()
    " place cursor on dbg
    call search('dbg\s*(', "W")
    " delete dbg with normal vim dw
    " here we use normal with ! to call default mappings
    normal! dw
    " use vim-surround mapping to remove ( )
    " note, here we use normal without !, to call mapping of vim-surround
    normal dsb
endfunc

" Search every line that has dbg( or dbg (  and exectute StripDbg() function on that line
command! -buffer -range StripDbg <line1>,<line2>g/dbg\s*(/call StripDbg()
```

Comment: Ad 2. Why not `autocmd filetype cpp ...` ?

Comment: Probably filetype cpp would be better, here

Comment: @Maxim Kim Thanks a lot for your answer. Isn't the current question self-standing? Even if I make a separate question, I would have to repeat the full example as well as the majority of the wording. Can you please expand your answer to complete the StripDbg() function?

Comment: @Krishna, I don't know what it should do. I can only assume but again it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MaximKim I have edited my question to describe the desired output after the strip operation.

Comment: @Krishna I have updated the answer. Bear in mind it uses `vim-surround` as I didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Note: the wheel is quite simple this time: `%x``x` -- but it messes registers. I've avoided the `:global`  path because it cannot handle simply cases where `dgb()`  appear twice on a same line. Fortunately, this is not required by OP.

Comment: @LucHermitte indeed, the wheel :), thx!

Comment: @Maxim Kim, thanks a lot for your nice answer. The two answers given so far worked well. I had to accept one, and it was a tough call for me (especially because I don't feel qualified enough to judge). Thank you once again. Your answer was really helpful to understand a bit more about setting up such/similar vimscript incantations for future needs and helped me learn something.